# Facebook Oauth2 - invalid scope id?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement facebook login/autoregister for a website. There is a problem with the requested scopes.

First I have tried to use the "default" scope. According to the official documentation, it provides access to a subset of the UserData structure. It is documented here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-default

However, if I try to do this, then I get an error:

```
Invalid scope: default
```

I have also tried to use something basic first. For example, scope="id". Then I get this error:

```
Invalid scope: id
```

If I try scope="email first_name last_name middle_name name picture" then:

```
Invalid scope: first_name
```

The only that worked so far is scope="email", but that is not enough for auto registration.

Moreover, the documentations cleary says that "All permissions, except the Default Public Profile fields, require Facebook Login and Client OAuth Login enabled for your app to allow Users or Pages to grant your app these permissions." (you can read this on the top of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/ ). So it seems that the scopes are not invalid because I don't have Facebook Login enabled for my app. They are invalid for some other reason - maybe because the don't exist?

I wonder why are these scopes documented if they are invalid? And where can I find the valid ones?

Side note: it seems that Facebook does not follow RFC 6749. When there is an error, the Oauth2 server (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2 more specifically 4.1.2.1 error response ). But Facebook does not do this. It displays a popup window on facebook.com instead, and if I press "OK" on that window, it enters an infinite loop and keeps displaying the same message again and again: "You are no logged in". (Why would I?)

**UPDATE**: Even though I used scope=email only, the /me api returned all fields, including first_name, last_name, email, and profile picture. So maybe those things are not scopes, but field names. But it is still unclear what scopes are available? The documentation still seems bad. It should clearly tell which terms are scopes, which are field names from data structures. And a complete list of scopes is still missing from the docs (or maybe there is a list, just I couldn't find it?)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are indeed a bit misleading, but "default" is not a permission/scope, it just tells you want data you can get WITHOUT an additional permission. You can find the available permissions in the link of your question, if you just scroll to the top. Only that list is important, for the default fields there is a link "Default Public Profile Fields", but - again - no scope/permission is needed.

And yes, there is a big difference between scope and fields. For example, the `email` field can be used after authorizing with the `email` scope, but the `birthday` field requires authorization with the `user_birthday` permission. Fields can be found here, for example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/user

Comment: "permission" and "scope" are two different things. Aren't they? I know exactly what a "scope" means, because it is documented in RFC 6749. But I have no idea what a "permission" means in this context. On the top of that page, there is a list indeed. It contains mostly permissions, but "Default User Profile Fields" is not a scope. At least they should mention that permission == scope, and that "Default User Profile Fields" is NOT a scope. I don't even understand why they put it in that list. It should be explained in a separate paragraph.

Comment: you add additional permissions with the scope parameter, for example: "scope=email,user_birthday,..."

Comment: And that is also not RFC 6749 compilant. The RFC says that scopes should be separated by spaces. It is true that Facebook API also accept spaces, but everybody seems to be using commas.

Comment: @nagylzs The Facebook Login API is not OAuth2 compliant. Neither the used terminology in their documentation.

Comment: oh yeah, and they explicitly write things like "To get an access token, make an HTTP GET request to the following OAuth endpoint" (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/). If their API is not Oauth compilant, then they should not use the term "oauth endpoint". That is very misleading.